# Which policy to choose between AdministratorAccess and Amazons3FullAccess

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-iam

For using s3 bucket which IAM policy need to be created AdministratorAccess or AmazonS3FullAccess or both together?

Answer (score 0):

You can use amazons3full access but I would suggest you to create a custom Iam policy which gives access to just that particular bucket .
Refer: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/security/writing-iam-policies-how-to-grant-access-to-an-amazon-s3-bucket/

Answer (score 0):

If you are the only person using the AWS Account, then **Administrator** permissions are fine.

If, however, multiple people are using the account, then you should **consider how to manage security** of the AWS Account and the resources *within* the account.

Only grant **Admin permissions** to people who are responsible for all systems. It has "All Access" (including Amazon S3), so it can be quite dangerous.

Similarly, granting `AmazonS3FullAccess` is not necessarily a wise move. It allows the recipient all access to S3, including the ability to delete buckets and objects.

Preferably, only allocate the permissions that each user actually needs to perform their job.